# How to setup facebook app for titanium android app?

Tags: android, facebook, titanium

Currently I am working on a Titaninum Android Application. First of all let me tell you I am noob about titanium SDK. I am learning it. I need to implement Facebook login in that application. I just registered a application on facebook. On facebook I noticed options for Native android App. I enabled it but it is asking for Android Key Hash, Android Package Name, Android Class Name and Android Market URI. Please can anyone guide me about these parameters and how do I set them in my application for application development and testing purpose ??

Comment: doesn't the [API Documentation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module) help? An remember, been a Titanium user, you can always access their own Forum where Appcelerator professionals read it every day and can help you better...

Comment: I checked that but I didn;t found anything about above mentioned parameters. Do I really require to set them to run my titanium android application ?

Comment: you can always try without them, give it a try, that's what developing is... keep trying until we succeed :)

Comment: agreed with you... after replying you I just tried that and worked.... too much happy ;). Today learnt that it is necessary to overcome fear of failure.. btw its my first day on android development.

Comment: um, what did you do to get this working?